# List customized using infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have a SharePoint list that was customized using infopath. There are picture controls and it is browser enabled. The issue is, when users try to upload pictures, it is asking the picture Address as a URL. We want the option to browse and upload.. why is it not doing so. Our users are not that computer savvy and may not be able to get the address of the picture. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You would have created a Hyperlink-type picture control. You will have to change the field's datatype to Picture or File Attachment which will let you browse and select the picture from desktop , You can try changing its data type else delete the control, and then re-create the control with the below data type.

[image]

[Change Control Type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-one-type-of-control-to-another-type-of-control-417a779c-8995-46c1-93fb-2aaf79696735)